# Etymology of "t" in t-test and t-distribution

Tags: t-test, terminology, t-distribution, history, etymology

I am aware of the fact that Gosset came up with *t*-distribution, but what is the etymology of "t"? How did "t" end up in *t*-test and *t*-distribution?

Answer (score 10):

It appears to have been done by Fisher as he was developing a more general theory of testing, although perhaps by Student in a letter to Fisher a couple of years before.  Originally Student denoted it by $z$, although it wasn't actually in its current form at that time (that had to wait for Fisher.)  If you have access, [The American Statistician (1979)](http://www.jstor.org/pss/2683058) has a paper on this.  If you don't, some brief comments are in http://jeff560.tripod.com/s.html.

Comment: Could you edit in a brief summary of the main points of the linked sites into your answer, in case there's issues with them later? (For example, for some reason I cannot successfully connect to the tripod.com site at the moment.)

Answer (score 6):

According to H.A. David's paper linked [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/17606/5594), "Student's *t*" and "*t*" were first used in R.A. Fisher's 1924 paper [*On a Distribution Yielding the Error Functions of Several Well Known Statistics*](http://www.mathunion.org/ICM/ICM1924.2/Main/icm1924.2.0805.0814.ocr.pdf).  The first occurrence is on page 809 where we see Fisher refer to "Student's curves" and uses the variable *t*.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's because "t" is the last letter of both Gossett and Student, which was his pen name.  Why choose the last letter?  Search me.

Comment: Gossett is a very common typo, but he really was Gosset. https://global.oup.com/academic/product/student-9780198522270