# Why moments of expectation are known as “moments”

Tags: expected-value, terminology, moments

I am studying moments of expectation, and seen the formulas for computing the moments. There is one thing I am not clear of, and not getting answer for that.

Why moments are named as moments? To my understanding, the word "moment" has relationship with time, so what is the role of time in computing expectation moments?

Comment: The terminology was introduced by analogy with moments in classical mechanics. Moments in time are not implied.

Comment: To quote Macbeth:  "Who can be wise, amazed, temperate and furious, Loyal and neutral, in a _moment_?" [Act ii. Sc. 3]

Comment: In physics moments are a combination of physical quantity and distance to some reference point. Variation about mean value is then quite naturally a moment (central moment).

Comment: @NickCox you were faster than I about this connection to physics (+1)

Comment: @Analyst You were only a moment behind....

Comment: In addition to the duplicate, also see http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/17595