# Name of third cumulant?

Tags: cumulants

The first cumulant is called the *mean*. The second is the *variance*.

Does the third cumulant have a name? The fourth?

Comment: Related: [Higher-order cumulant and moment names beyond variance, skewness and kurtosis](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/188281/higher-order-cumulant-and-moment-names-beyond-variance-skewness-and-kurtosis)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The third and fourth cumulants do not have specific sames, but their *standardised* versions do.  The third and fourth standardised cumulants are given respectively by the [skewness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skewness#Pearson's_moment_coefficient_of_skewness) and the [excess kurtosis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurtosis#Excess_kurtosis):

$$\gamma = \frac{\mu_3}{\mu_2^{3/2}}
\quad \quad \quad \quad \quad
\kappa_* = \kappa - 3 = \frac{\mu_4}{\mu_2^2} - 3.$$

The skewness is a measure of the left or right skew in the data.  The kurtosis is a measure of the fatness of the tails of the distribution, and the "excess kurtosis" is the amount in excess of mesokurtosis (i.e., the amount in excess of a normal distribution).

Answer (score 1):

The third [cumulant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulant) is the third central moment, i.e. $\kappa_3=\mu_3=E[(X-E[X])^3]$. But, the fourth cumulant is not the fourth central moment. Specifically, it is the [following](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Cumulant.html):
$$\kappa_4=\mu_4-3\mu_2^2$$
where $\mu_i$ is the i-th central moment. I haven't seen it being referred as other than cumulant (on its own). Otherwise, it's worth noting @whuber's comment:

> When standardized as $\kappa_4/\mu_2^2 = \mu_4/\mu_2^2-3$, it is called "excess kurtosis." A common name for the standardized third cumulant $\kappa_3/\mu_2^{3/2}$ is "skewness." – [whuber](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/919/whuber)

Comment: When standardized as $\kappa_4/\mu_2^2 = \mu_4/\mu_2^2-3,$ it is called "excess kurtosis."  A common name for the standardized third cumulant $\kappa_3/\mu_2^{3/2}$ is "skewness."