# The use of a pseudo variance $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \text{sign}(x) (x-\mu)^2 f(x) dx$ in place of $\int_{-\infty}^\infty (x-\mu)^2 f(x) dx$

Tags: mathematical-statistics, variance, terminology, median, moments

#### Difference between odd central moments and even central moments

When we compute $n$-th central moments

$$\mu_n = \int_{-\infty}^\infty (x-\mu)^nf(x) dx$$

then there is a difference in interpretation of the cases when $n$ is odd or even.

- For even $n$ the expression $(x-\mu)^n$ is always positive.

  This central moment describes the spread of the values in the distribution away from the moment, without considering whether the value $(x-\mu)$ is negative or not.
- For odd $n$ the expression $(x-\mu)^n$ is positive for $x>\mu$ and negative for $x<\mu$.

  The **odd moments incorporate some difference between the left and right side** of the distribution (and the even moments do not).

#### Making odd central moments like even central moments.

There is a definition of moments where the odd moments get the same type of interpretation as the even moments, and that is when we have the [absolute central moment](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/AbsoluteMoment.html) (which occurs for instance [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/479558)).

$$\mu^\prime_n = \int_{-\infty}^\infty |x-\mu|^nf(x) dx$$

for even $n$ this expression is the same as the regular central moment $\mu^\prime_n = \mu_n$.

#### Making even central moments like odd central moments.

We could also turn it the other way around and make even central moments with the negative and positive components in a similar way as the odd central moments, by including the sign in the expression.

$$\mu^\dagger_n = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \text{sign}(x-\mu) |x-\mu|^nf(x) dx$$

for odd $n$ this expression is the same as the regular central moment $\mu^\dagger_n = \mu_n$.

Some applications might be when $n=0$ in which case $\mu^\dagger_n$ expresses the difference in the probability mass left and right of the mean. I imagine that there might have been uses for $n=2$ or higher as well. For instance as an alternative for skewness.

**Has this type of pseudo-moment been used before and are there names for it?**

Comment: This answer here is why I thought of this question https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/561770/164061

Comment: "Semivariance" (although it has several meanings) is one term that has been used for a closely related concept.  It is employed in some forms of risk analysis.