Isn't kurtosis poorly defined if it doesn't take into account skewness?
Apologies in advance, I am not a statistician so this question may be naive. The way I understand things is as follows:
The mean is the first raw moment.
Variance is the second central moment, i.e. obtained after subtracting the first raw moment (the mean). The second raw moment may be useful in specific contexts but doesn't really describe an aspect of the shape of a distribution or dataset (not without taking into account the mean of the dataset).
Similarly, skewness is the third standardised moment, i.e. obtained after subtracting the mean and dividing by the standard deviation (the root of the variance).
But kurtosis is the fourth standardised moment. It is also a standardised moment, i.e it doesn't take into account any third moment (skewness).
Isn't this problematic for the interpretation of kurtosis? If not, why not? If yes, is there a way to interpret kurtosis that takes skewness into account?
(Am I right in saying that there isn't a simple way to 'deskew', i.e. no simple transformation analogous to centralisation and standardisation that would result in mean 0, standard deviation/variance 1 and skewness 0?)

Often in practice, high skewness (as measured through moments) goes with high kurtosis (ditto) as both react to weighty tails. L-moments can be more successful at distinguishing different properties. The biggest problem of all is what Whitehead called misplaced concreteness, thinking and acting as if each name (skewness, kurtosis) points to a single latent property to be measured in just one way.

Not directly answering your question, but, in my experience, interpreting kurtosis as a pure numerical value is not intuitive at all, and doesn't improve much with practice. To interpret it, I would use a plot. Probably a density plot or a quantile normal plot or maybe a box plot.

There's certainly a connection between skewness and kurtosis, in that kurtosis is always at least 1 more than the square of skewness. See this plot, from here ($\beta_1$ is the square of skewness, $\beta_2$ is kurtosis); the plot shows the regions covered by various members of the Pearson distributions. ... ctd

Following up @Glen_b, there are mathematical inequalities connecting these moments, but otherwise there's no restriction: any mathematically possible pair of (skewness, kurtosis) values can arise from some distribution. You can indeed extend the concept of normalization to factor out skewness, but (almost by definition) that would require a nonlinear transformation--and there are so many of those available that there's no unique or best way to accomplish it. See Box-Cox.

... ctd  As such, subtracting the square of skewness would give you the extra part of the fourth moment that could not possibly be explained by the skewness. On the plot plotting $\beta_1$ vs $\beta_2-\beta_1^2$ would straighten the grey region to a vertical bar.  I don't think I've seen anyone do it but there's no reason why you couldn't. As whuber notes, there's no unique or best approach to trying to separate them

While it may not directly answer your question, you may find this well written paper by D. Wheeler interesting: https://www.spcpress.com/pdf/DJW387.pdf. Quoting his last paragraph, " skewness and kurtosis essentially ignore the central
95% of the data in any histogram. So you should return the favor by ignoring the
skewness and kurtosis statistics provided by your software. There is simply
nothing to be learned from these so-called shape statistics."

Why do you think it is problematic for the interpretation of kurtosis? Kurtosis has a very precise interpretation, no matter what is the skewness.

@jginestet thanks for that interesting paper. I have to say that while I started out wanting to go along with that argument, I ended up unconvinced — isn't the entire point of skewness and kurtosis that they say something about the tails?

@BigBendRegion that seems to run counter to some of the other comments, in particular the plot posted by Glen_b. But I would welcome your answer if you could explain this precise interpretation.

See https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/481022/102879. The discussion in the beginning about "falling to the right" of the fulcrum, for m=4, provides a precise interpretation. If the kurtosis of one distribution is higher than that of another, then the "falls to the right" phenomenon holds. Skewness doesn't matter in this precise interpretation.

You can use a similar "falling to the right or left" argument to give a precise interpretation of skewness in terms of the distributions of the third moment of the z scores.

My question to the OP is, how did you think kurtosis was supposed to be interpreted?

@BigBendRegion I don't know, that's why I'm asking. Thanks for the link to your other answer, that's very informative. I guess my point is that in a very skewed dataset, I wouldn't attach the same degree of 'outlierness' to a point at x standard deviations from the mean than in a non-skewed dataset. Or more specifically (but correct me if this is a bad example), I am looking for an interpretation that values the kurtosis of a normal distribution and the kurtosis of the corresponding log-normal distribution equally.
